# How to move files from one directory to another

Tags: mv

I downloaded a few files under a folder that was stored in the "downloads" option on my pc, as usual. But I need to move it to the working directory of Ubuntu. What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: Have you explore just using `mv` or move itself?   If you're unsure of what commands are available ; you could always `apropos move` and see what command options are available (ie. search the reference manual pages).  What is your trouble with `mv` ??

Comment: what is a "working directory"? If the download is an installer... you don't.